# Terminal Command that ends script

Tags: python, terminal

Wondering how i would code into a script so that if the user inputs the command it will end the process of that script. For example, i run *scriptname.py* and have it coded in there that when *terminalcommand* is entered into terminal, it will close down that script.

Will this also force close the script? Or will it still have run through the code and then closed it. I have it coded right now so that when i press q it closes the program having run through the code but i want to be able to do that in terminal.

```
cv2.imshow("Diff", frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
if key == ord('q'):
   break
```

Currently i have it coded like that so when i press q it will end the task.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you post your code? Maybe it's easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: how about `sys.exit()` ? do you want to exit python, or the terminal it's running on?

Comment: Just to see if I understood the problem correctly, you want to end the python code by entering a command in a different terminal right?

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ Yes thats what i want to do, see code i added for the way it currently ends the script.

Comment: try to replace `break` by `sys.exit()`, and if it doesn't work try `os._exit(0)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ok and then what command would i enter into terminal to close it?

Comment: sorry but not sure I understand your question after all

Comment: Teshan: _"You want to end the python code by entering a command in a different terminal right?"_ Marcin: _"Yes thats what i want to do"_  — then I think it's a problem related to the OS you are using and the answer would be different for  Mac/BSD/Linux or WIndows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give an external input to your code. One easy way for this is using a named pipe (assuming you are on a Linux OS). Create a named file using

```
mkfifo mypipe
```

Now in python, you can open the named pipe

```
import os
pipe = os.fdopen(os.open('mypipe', os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK))
```

You can ignore the `O_NONBLOCK` flag if your code doesn't have anything else to do while you are waiting for the input. Then it will wait for something to be written in the pipe.

So now for waiting you can use a while loop to check if your pipe received the command you want.

```
while pipe.read().rstrip() != "terminalcommand":
    #something to do while waiting. time.sleep() maybe? Or just pass
```

If you do not know how named pipes behave, you can write something to it just like a normal file. Since now the code waits for `terminalcommand`, you can do

```
echo terminalcommand > mypipe
```

in the terminal to exit the while loop. If you want to have a single command, create an alias in the terminal.

```
alias stopmyprogram="echo terminalcommand > [directory to mypipe]/mypipe"
```

You can make the alias globally available by adding that line to the file `~/.bash_aliases`